# Text reflection effect

Tags: transparency, text-decorations, gradient

How could I achieve with LaTeX a [trendy text reflection effect](http://inkscapetutorials.org/2007/06/22/text-reflection-using-inkscape/) as the following one?
[image]

Comment: The code for this is actually on the cover of PGF/TikZ manual.

Comment: Indeed: though I heavily searched a solution in the `TikZ` manual, I just didn't look at the cover page :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mytext{Reflec\textcolor{red}{t}ion}
  \tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0,font=\ttfamily\Huge}}
  \node[mynode]{\mytext};
  \node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,mynode]{\mytext};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** To remove the gap between the node and its reflection, you may use `anchor=base` or `line width=0`.

**Note 2:** Unlike Inkscape, TikZ does not know the *true* bounding box of glyphs:

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the anchor on the baseline center?

Comment: @Sigur Its name is `base`...

Comment: @SIgur ... and I edited my answer. ;-)