# Is there a (simple) way to find out if a command is executed in a tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

Assume I want to use some nice Ti*k*Z feature, such as [casting a shadow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209667/121799), or something else. I may want to do that inside or outside a tikzpicture environment. So I am wondering if there is a (simple) way to find out if a command is executed in a tikzpicture environment. To be more specific, consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzset{CastShadow/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0,font=\ttfamily\Huge}}
\newcommand{\CastShadowOutsideTikZ}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(temp.base)]
  \node[CastShadow,#1](temp){#2};
  \node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,CastShadow,#1]{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\CastShadowInsideTikZ}[2][]{
  \node[CastShadow,#1]{#2};
  \node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,CastShadow,#1]{#2};
}

\begin{document}
\CastShadowOutsideTikZ{Quack} \CastShadowOutsideTikZ[scale=2]{Quack}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\CastShadowInsideTikZ[at={(0,0)},scale=2]{Feep}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to unify the commands `\CastShadowOutsideTikZ` and `\CastShadowInsideTikZ` to a single command `\CastShadow`, which behaves like `\CastShadowInsideTikZ` when called within a tizkpicture and like `\CastShadowOutsideTikZ` otherwise.

(I am aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327858/121799)), but my question is whether there is a simpler way.)

Comment: Related Question: [Detecting if inside a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458849/4301)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make the code below more robust by adding an error message in the fourth argument of `\apptocmd`, just in case TikZ internals were to change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newtoggle{intikz}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\tikz@startup@env}{\toggletrue{intikz}}{}{}
\makeatother
\tikzset{CastShadow/.style={anchor=south,inner sep=0,font=\ttfamily\Huge}}
\newcommand{\CastShadowOutsideTikZ}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(temp.base)]
  \node[CastShadow,#1](temp){#2};
  \node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,CastShadow,#1]{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\CastShadowInsideTikZ}[2][]{
  \node[CastShadow,#1]{#2};
  \node[scope fading=south,opacity=0.4,yscale=-1,CastShadow,#1]{#2};
}
\newcommand\CastShadow{\iftoggle{intikz}{\CastShadowInsideTikZ}{\CastShadowOutsideTikZ}}
\begin{document}
\CastShadow{Quack} \CastShadowOutsideTikZ[scale=2]{Quack}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\CastShadow[at={(0,0)},scale=2]{Feep}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, all bets are off if you place a non-tikz environment inside your tikz environment! (It could be handled too, with a bit more work. You would just have to toggle `intikz` off on entry to *every* environment.)